# How do I hide the borders of the columns of an HTML table row in print preview ONLY where the row overlaps the footer?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have the following scenario: A report where the first column may span multiple rows - could be 200 rows. The footer will be displayed on every page in print preview.

I need to hide the borders of the overlapping first column in the footer.

The following works for the last page of the report where there is no overlap.

```css
@media print {

.myReport tfoot>tr>td {
  border: none !important;
}

.myReport tfoot {
  border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="200">Group Header</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <!-- 199 more times -->
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="table-footer">
      <td colspan="3">AAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAAAA</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

How do I hide the borders of the columns of an HTML table row in print preview ONLY where the it overlaps the footer?

[image]

The line through **Viewing 1-10** is from the multi-row column not the footer.

Comment: try adding media query for print

Comment: i fixed your sample so that we can see what's going on a little better. @Marx, can you rephrase your question in terms of the blue, green, and red borders I've added?

Comment: What does "hide the borders of the overlapping first column in the footer" mean? Can you draw a little diagram?

Comment: @duhaime I mean a cell in the first column starts on page 2, it's border is visible in the footer and continues on page 3. The footer has a colspan of "all columns" so no borders should be visible in the footer.  Make sense?

Comment: @jhchnc - I don't see blue, green, or red borders.

Comment: @Marx my edit wasn't approved.  No idea why.  

In any case, adding colored output to your question would be helpful.

Comment: I approved the edit but it needs another approval. One reviewer might have thought you are making substantive changes to the code, which is true but helpful. I'm still not clear what the goal is here :/

Comment: The image makes it clear now - or no?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to raise the stack order in the footer.

```
@media print {
    tfoot > tr > td.multiColumn {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="200">Group Header</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <!-- 199 more times -->
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="table-footer">
      <td class="multiColumn" colspan="3">AAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAAAA</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```